# Group by year then group by month with its own collections

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have this LINQ

```
var summary =
    from b in books
    group b by b.DateAdded.Value.Year.ToString() into newgroup
        from newgrour2 in
        (
            from b in newgroup
            group b by new
            {
                month = b.DateAdded.Value.ToString("MMMM")
            }
        )
        group new Monthly
        {
            Month = newgrour2.Key.month,
            Count = newgrour2.Count()
        } by new
        {
            Year = newgroup.Key.ToString(),
            Count = newgroup.Count()
        };
```

which can be fetch by

```
foreach (var year in Summary)
{
    var y = year.Key.Year;
    var cc = year.Key.Count;
    foreach (var month in year)
    {
        var m = month.Month;
        var c = month.Count;
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
2018 - 5 in total
    May - 3 items
    June - 1 item
    July - 1 item
2017 - 4 in total
    February - 4 items
```

My problem is that I don't want this part to be anonymous

```
new { Year = newgroup.Key.ToString(), Count = newgroup.Count() };
```

But if I replace this to

```
new Yearly { Year = newgroup.Key.ToString(), Count = newgroup.Count() };
```

It doesn't really group by year; it just goes intp one list.

How do I make the same output but not an anonymous?

if I do this with the anonymous type,
`summary` contains 2 items - 2018 and 2017 which is correct
`year` will now contains its own months
But if I do this with `Yearly`, `summary` will contain all items as one list. No sub items.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "It doesn't really group by year; it just goes intp one list."? The way you have written `new Yearly { Year = newgroup.Key.ToString(), Count = newgroup.Count() };` is the correct way to replace the anonymous type.

Comment: Is your Linq code valid? I've never seen `group by new Foo { ... } by new { ... }`. Can you rewrite your Linq using only extension-methods? (I find them much more clearer and easier to work with than the C# Linq syntax).

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited my question

Comment: I'm not comfortable with extension method

Comment: can you post `book` class structure?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. I just need to group by year and by month and its total